# adding jquery onto a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm having some trouble adding a javascript variable onto the end of my link here's my code

```
var locid = $.trim($(this > '.locid').text());
```

`$(this).prepend('<a class="booknow2" href="../../availability/default.aspx?propid=' + locid + '"><span>Check availability &raquo;</span></a>');`

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a direct child when you already have another element, use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), like this:

```
var locid = $.trim($(this).children('.locid').text());
```

You can't really use `$(this ...anything)`, you *can* however use `$(this).something()`, and that `.something()` could be any of [the tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to move around.

Comment: Brilliant thanks it works - you answered it so quick I can't accept your answer yet lol